# plot points on a line where certain conditions are met based on another series in R

Tags: r, plot, points

I have following data

```
a<- rnorm(10)*10+100
b<- c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1)
```

First i would like to plot a line with

```
plot(a)
```

And then i would like to plot points wherever there is **1** in the series **b** .

Please help me. I am really stuck.

Comment: why down vote guys ? i am very new in R. i only know few commands in R. I searched the forum for possible clues. but failed. If this question is answered before please give me reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ifelse` you can choose value in vector "a" to be plotted:

```
ifelse(b==1,a,0)
```

To get lines (not the default points) in the first plot , you should use `type="l"`.

The code can be something like this :

```
set.seed(1)   ## I set the seed here to get a reproducible example
a<- rnorm(10)*10+100
b<- c(0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1)
plot(a,type='l')
points(ifelse(b==1,a,0),col='red',pch=20,cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot @agstudy for quick response.